# How to know what are all the possible parameters for a query string for a site?

Tags: url, parameters

I want to check what are ALL the possible parameters for any existing website url. Assuming the site is working with parameters type query string "architecture" (and not MVC for example) something like:

`http://www.foobar.com/p1&itemsPerPage=50&size=500`

Let's say there are other parameters which I don't know exist, and I don't see them in the url at the moment. For example, parameters like `max`, `day` and `OtherExoticVariable`. Again, I don't know their names but want to know ALL of their names. Is there some way of requesting the server to respond will all possible url parameters?

I would prefer a method with Javascript that I could run quickly through a browser but could also do asp.net c# if necessary.

Thanks a lot!

Ray.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the script/app running on the server that decides what parameters are valid. Unless the app provides such a query mechanism you can't do it. The server has no idea what is valid and what isn't.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think this is possible. Each Web application designer can decide on the parameters individually, and you only know them if you see them being used.

Comment: It could be possible by brute-forcing.

Answer (score 5):

Not guaranteed to get you ALL query strings, but it is often helpful to Google
`"foobar.com/p1& * "`.

You will be able to see all the public occurrences of query strings for the foobar.com website.

(As the accepted answer says, there is no general method to access query strings unless the website provides an API.)